# A word/phrase for "being extremely happy and jumping gladly"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Suppose if someone is extremely happy like a child and starts jumping gladly, what words/phrase best describe this situation, such that the following sentence can be completed.

> He/she was  ________.

There are a few words like, "euphoric", "deliriously happy", but I am not quite sure if these words also include the "jumping gladly" part of my question.

Is there a better word or using "jumping gladly" is just fine.

Comment: The expression: [happy as a sandboy](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-happy-as-a-sandboy.html) springs to mind.

Comment: Does the answer ***have to*** include the term **jumping**? In other words are you looking for a term which means "to jump up and down happily"? Or do you want to know the idiomatic equivalent of "jumping gladly" is? The question is unclear judging by the answers submitted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA:I would be glad to know a term which means "to jump up and down happily".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for :

[Jump for joy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/jump-for-joy):

> - to be extremely happy:
>
>   - *Tina jumped for joy when she found out she'd be in the team.*
>   - *"So how did Robert take the news?" "He didn't exactly jump for joy."* (Cambridge Dict.)

The expression can refer both to  physical and metaphorical Joyful jumps.

[image]

Comment: I don't think `Jump for joy ` implies literally jumping.

Comment: Well, I think the expression clearly  refers  to that, both physically and metaphorically . http://mindtechnology.com/assets/images/Man_Jump_for_Joy.jpg. Is the guy in the picture jumping for joy?

Comment: Apt answer, great illustration of same, +1

Comment: [*Leap for joy*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leap+for+joy) also. +1

Comment: so many answers but "jump for joy" fits best for me to be filled in the blank left in my sentence.

Answer (score 9):

A word that fits the bill pretty perfectly is *giddy*. This word is used to describe childishly obnoxious joy. A giddy person is pretty much always smiling, usually giggling or laughing, and typically dancing and/or jumping, bouncing, or otherwise being energetic.

Answer (score 5):

*[Exult](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exult)* has the denotation of joy:

> verb
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>   Show or feel triumphant elation or jubilation:
>
> ODO

It contains the [connotation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=exult&allowed_in_frame=0) of *leap*:

> 1560s, "to ***leap*** up;" 1590s, "to rejoice, triumph,"
>   from Middle French
>   exulter,
>   from Latin exultare/exsultare "rejoice exceedingly, revel,
>   vaunt, boast;"
>   **literally "*leap about, leap up***,"
>   frequentative of
>   exsilire "to leap up,"
>   from ex- "out" (see ex-) + salire "to leap"
>   (see *[salient](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=salient&allowed_in_frame=0)* (adj.)).
>   The notion is of leaping or dancing for joy.
>   Related: Exulted; exulting.

*She was **exulting** in her victory*

Answer (score 2):

It might take a bit of imagining on the part of the reader, but the following suggestion might evoke the idea of "jumping gladly" that you want:

> She was ***[over the moon](http://www.betterspokenenglish.com/idioms-over-the-moon/)***.

(The link is not to a well-established dictionary, I'm afraid.)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to describe someone who is actually jumping up and down gladly, you can say:

> He/she was **literally** [jumping for joy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jump-for-joy?q=jump%20for%20joy)..

(To improve on Josh's answer)

The expression means:

> Be ecstatically happy:

and can be used in situations where one is happy but standing still. According to the  definition, physically jumping isn't implied. That's why this is one place where `literally` could come in handy to mean literally, not figuratively.

[Oxford]

Comment: I didn't down you (pinky swear!), but I'm betting whoever did, did so because your answer is too close/similar to Josh's. Maybe your suggestion of "add *literally*" would be better as a comment under his answer? And on that note, it's a sad fact that *literally* has developed a secondary sense of *figuratively* (arrgh!) which some people can't stomach. It could be the case that one of those people read your answer and didn't realize you meant literally *literally*, and downvoted you because they believed you used the word to mean *figuratively* (i.e. to add emphasis).

Comment: @DanBron: I tried commenting below Josh's answer. He disagreed and seemed to think that literally was implied in the idiom. I didn't think so. Hence the answer. Should I take it down?

Comment: @DanBron: I NEVER use literally to mean figuratively. I don't care that dictionaries allow it.

Comment: The answer doesn't bug me. If the downvotes don't bug you (bearing in mind it's always possible you'll receive more) there's no reason to take it down. Having said that, making suggestions on or disagreeing with the nuances of a particular answer is very common, as is the author of the answer rejecting or ignoring those suggestions. Often a comment on an answer serves as much as a signpost to *other* users as it does as a suggestion to that one particular author. If others agree with you, the comment will get upvoted. That may ultimately persuade the author; if not, the upv'd comment is there.

Comment: I believe that the source of the phrase is literal---I, myself, have been known to occasionally jump for (or, *with*) joy (Super Bowl XLIX)---though the meaning has expanded and now includes the figurative or pseudo-jumping sense. Josh's graphic illustration is a superb example of the true-jumping sense, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

He was “skipping with unbridled exuberance”

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word "ebullient" for the cheerful part.

Depending on which dictionary you use, the origin seems to come from 'boiling up' -- a bit of a stretch to equate it with jumping, but it might work for what you need it for.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the word "Ecstasy" and can be described as below.

*If you’ve ever been so happy that the rest of the world seemed to disappear, you’ve felt ecstasy — a feeling or state of intensely beautiful bliss.*

In your sample question.He was **screaming in ecstasy**.

Read more about this [www.vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ecstasy).

Comment: Hey Krishna. The link is helpful: would you mind quoting the relevant parts of that page directly within your answer? Also, there's a new policy EL&U adopted this year that links should say the name of the site that they're linking to (in your case, that means mentioning vocabulary.com by name).

Comment: @DanBron : now it looks gud?

Comment: Very good! If you like, you can use the blockquote formatting directive `>` , but that's certainly not mandatory. The only other thing I could suggest is changing the last sentence to make it clearer the actual quote came from vocabulary.com rather than only advice to go visit that site.

Answer (score 1):

FULL OF PISS AND VINEGAR... To say that people are “full of piss and vinegar” is to say that they are brimming with energy. Although many speakers assume the phrase must have a negative connotation, this expression is more often used as a compliment, “vinegar” being an old slang term for enthusiastic energy.

[Phrasefinder.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/piss-and-vinegar.html): **'Full of piss and vinegar'**

Rowdy, boisterous, full of youthful energy.

> The earliest citation I've found is from 1936 in John Steinbeck's
> novel In Dubious Battle:
>
> "Listen, mister," London said, "them guys is so full of piss and
> vinegar they'll skin you if you show that slick suit outside."

Steinbeck was clearly pleased with the phrase (although it is unlikely that he coined it himself) and repeated the use of it 1938 in his better known novel The Grapes of Wrath:

> Grampa walked up and slapped Tom on the chest, and his eyes grinned with affection and pride. "How are ya, Tommy?"
>
> "O.K.," said Tom. "How ya keepin' yaself?"
>
> "Full a piss an' vinegar," said Grampa.

Answer (score 0):

He/she was ... *ecstatically jubilant*, *uncontrollably elated*, *rambunctious* and *overjoyed*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Question marks in answers raise flags. Please don't use question marks in answers: make a definite answer which you can support with a corroborative quote. Also, it would be good to check spelling.

Answer (score 0):

The best single-word answer would be [gamboling](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gambol).

> to skip about, as in dancing or playing; frolic.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *gambol* (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought it added something useful to the discussion but please feel free to delete it.